# How to configure config.php in include folder

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, config

How to configure `config.php` in include folder..

```
$config['basedir']     =  '/home/username/public_html';
$config['baseurl']     =  'localhost';
```

I am using xampp in windows7 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seeming to be a bit out of context - what exactly are you using the $config array for? What application are you trying to install?

Either way, the basedir variable you have sounds like a UNIX based XAMPP one, it should probably be something like "C:\xampp\htdocs\" on your windows installation.

As for the baseurl, try maybe adding "http://" before it.

Comment: I am seeing following error ..                Notice: Undefined variable: config in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\index.php on line 17

Comment: Can you post the part in your index.php that gives the Error? Other than that, it seems to throw a Notice, not an Error - that shouldn't break your script - nonetheless you should probably adjust the ERROR_REPORTING in your PHP configuration.